# ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (4), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of labels (3). SEARCH STACK OVERFLOW

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, label, conv-neural-network

I am getting such an error while drawing confusion matrix, how do I fix it? I have 3 classes labeled 1,2,3.

```
Why are there 0's?
[[0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.97457126 0.03435805 0.         0.        ]
 [0.01833235 0.94876432 0.00238095 0.        ]
 [0.00709639 0.01687764 0.99761905 0.        ]]
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
#Predict
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

y_prediction = model.predict(testX)
y_prediction = np.argmax (y_prediction, axis = 1)
#testY=np.argmax(testY, axis=1)
#Create confusion matrix and normalizes it over predicted (columns)
labels = ['1', '2', '3']
result = confusion_matrix(testY, y_prediction , normalize='pred')
print(result)


cm = confusion_matrix(testY, y_prediction)

disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=labels)

disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

I am getting such an error while drawing confusion matrix, how do I fix it? I have 3 classes labeled 1,2,3.

Comment: How can you have a 4x4 confusion matrix when you have just 3 labels? I think maybe because your labels don't start with 0.

Comment: When tagging my labels, I only made 1,2 and 3. So what should I do in this situation?

Comment: maybe, try with the 4 if you have 4

Comment: My labels are 1, 2 and 3 but why is it printing matrix like 4x4?

Comment: Try to get the unique numbers from you y_prediction and testY, and compare. I think there must be some difference.